# Trigger on standard oracle base table recommended ? Oracle application

Tags: java, oracle, triggers, eventtrigger, erp

I want to write trigger on oracle application( ERP) one of the vital base table wf_notifications , from this trigger I will be calling a java concurrent program using fnd_request.submit_request  , all of my operations I will be doing in this java class file used in concurrent program . so will other operations affect if concurrent program fails ???  on other side oracle dose'nt recommend writing triggers on oracle standard base tables

Answer (score 0):

If you put a trigger on a table and the trigger throws an exception your DML statement (insert, update, delete) will fail with that exception.

You can put an catch all exception handler in the trigger to make sure your DML continues to work even if the trigger fails but you may never no that there is a problem with the triggered function.

So that would be something along these lines:

```
create or replace trigger mytrigger
  before insert or update or delete
  on mytable 
  for each row
declare

begin
  fnd_request.submit_request;
exception
  -- Hide whatever error this trigger throws at us.
  when others then null;
end mytrigger;
```

Also, the trigger could slow down your table inserts and updates because of the extra work being done.